# Symfony + NGINX = upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

Tags: symfony, nginx, fastcgi

Attempt to open Symfony web application in browser ends with 502 error.
NGINX log contains error for this -- upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream.
According to many advices did the following changes in nginx.conf in http context:

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 4k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 60k;
```

NGINX configuration file for Symfony web application looks like adviced in official documentation:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name neuro3.vbulash.site;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html/neuro3/public;
  index index.html index.php;

  charset utf-8;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off; log_not_found off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off; log_not_found off;
  }

  access_log off;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    internal;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/neuro3.vbulash.site.error.log;
}
```

It works for Laravel, but produces the error "upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream" for Symfony.
How to fix this?

Comment: Could you try this: `large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;`

Comment: Try to use this: `fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;` I had similar problem

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco still no effect (((

Comment: @Skuti same error

Comment: Just to be sure, you did restart Nginx after each change right ? :p

Comment: @Skuti exactly!